# Powershell Error when trying to open last modified file

Tags: powershell

So im trying to pull a datalist of programs from another computer on the sever and convert it into a csv file on a location in my computer. That part is working successfully however when im trying to open the latest created csv with powershell im facing an error.

```
<#User details#>
$user = „administrator“
$password = cat filesystem::c:\Users\praktikant2\Desktop\mingifail.txt | convertto-securestring
$me = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user, $password   

$list = Invoke-Command -cn Fillerhere -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName, Publisher, Version, EstimatedSize, UninstallString} -Credential $me
$list | Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, Version, EstimatedSize, UninstallString | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\praktikant2\Desktop\Loetelud\progloetelu$((get-date).tostring('dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss')).csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'  
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
$path = gci C:\Users\praktikant2\Desktop\Lists | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1  
$excel.Visible = $false
$openfile = $excel.workbooks.open($path);
```

Error message (a bit crudely translated) It even seems to recognize the file that was created since it names the right file which does exist in the specified location

```
Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Unit progloetelu09-02-2016-02-16-02.csv not found. Is it possible that it's been moved,renamed or deleted?"
At line:16 char:1

 + $openfile = $excel.workbooks.open($path);
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: Try with the full path to the file, instead of just the file name: `$openfile = $excel.workbooks.open($path.FullName)`

Comment: 1) The error message looks odd. There is a '>' where there should be a '-' Maybe you typed it in wrong, but if not, something else is going on. 2) The fact that the error message names the file doesn't mean the system found the file. It is just outputting the value you passed to open(). 3) `$path` is an `IO.FileInfo` object. Somehow PS converts it to just the filename when calling excel's open(). (Maybe it executes `$path.tostring()`). Since there is no directory specified, excel doesn't find the file. If you use `$path.fullname` instead, excel will get the full path.

Comment: Thank you $path.fullname did fix the problem. And the > really was just a typo here.